# How to use an image in the input group in Bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I am new to the web development, I am currently using the `glyphicon`

and the way I am using is ,

```
const className = `form-group ${touched && error ? 'has-danger' : ''}`;

<div className={className}>
    <div className="input-group">
        <div className="input-group-prepend">
            <span className="input-group-text"><i className={field.icon} aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        </div>
        <input className="form-control" type={field.type} placeholder={field.placeholder} {...field.input} />
    </div>
    <div className="invalid-feedback d-block error">
        {touched ? error : ''}
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, Here I want to use an image rather than using the glyphicon ,

Right now it looks liken
[image]

So, I have an image which I want to use instead of tthis?nt awsome icon.

so, can any one help me with this ?

what I want to do  is

[image]

Output I got

[image]

Comment: change this line : `<i className={field.icon} aria-hidden="true"></i>`

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the icon (`<i>...</i>`) with an `<img>`, and use bootstrap classes to remove the background and borders, like so;

Remove the borders with CSS, or use the bootstrap class `border-0` - [Bootstrap documentation on borders](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/borders/) and `bg-transparent` - [bootstrap documentation on colours](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/colors/)

*Note: The code below is slightly different to yours in order to create a working snippet, but the principle is the same.*

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="input-group mb-3 border">
  <div class="input-group-prepend bg-transparent">
    <span class="input-group-text bg-transparent  border-0" id="basic-addon1">
       <img src="https://art.pixilart.com/d200f77a5789629.png" style="width: 16px; height: 16px;" />
    </span>
  </div>
  <input type="text" class="form-control border-0" placeholder="Username" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
</div>
```

Comment: Hey but I actually dont want to have that borders as wel

Comment: I have just updated the image which kind of structure I desire

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Actually because of that input group it distinguish between the input and that image

Comment: Yes, you'll have to play around with the styling a little bit (focus, hover etc).

Comment: I have updated the output which I got form using this soultion

Comment: one more thing is that I have used the form-group as well